# Regex to remove all non-Alphanumeric characters with universal language support?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I would like to use Pattern's *compile* method to do this. Such as

```
String text = "Where? What is that, an animal? No! It is a plane.";
Pattern p = new Pattern("*some regex here*");
String delim = p.matcher(text).replaceAll("");
```

What is the regex that can do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Example strings:

English

```
Input: "Where? What is that, an animal? No! It is a plane."
Output: "Where What is that an animal No It is a plane"
```

Spanish

```
Input: "¿Dónde? ¿Qué es eso, un animal? ¡No! Es un avión."
Output: "Dónde Qué es eso un animal No Es un avión"
```

Portuguese

```
Input: "Onde? O que é isso, um animal? Não! É um avião."
Output: "Onde O que é isso um animal Não É um avião"
```

Hopefully the examples make it clear what I'm trying to accomplish.
Thanks all!

Comment: Suggesting this for Mandarin makes no sense, as characters are neither vowels nor letters, but rather logical sounds.  As for the romance language examples you gave us, you might have to list things out manually.

Comment: Every language has own symbols which are presented in different places of the ASCII tables. Also, you need to inspect it detail and create appropriate chains like [^a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: Non alphanumerical is \W (unless you don't want underscores either)

Comment: Space is a non-alphanumeric character, so output would be `"WhereWhatisthatananimalNoItisaplane"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, which is Java's implementation of regex, supports [Unicode Categories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode), e.g. `\p{Lu}`. Since you want alphanumeric, that would be [Categories](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) `L` (Letter) and `N` (Number).

Since your example shows you also want to keep spaces, you need to include that. Let's use the [Predefined Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) `\s`, so you also get to keep newlines and tabs.

To find anything but the specified characters, use a [Negation Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes): `[^abc]`

All-in-all, that means `[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]`:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("[^\\s\\p{L}\\p{N}]+", "");
```

```
Where What is that an animal No It is a plane
Dónde Qué es eso un animal No Es un avión
Onde O que é isso um animal Não É um avião
```

Or see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nCTadD/1) for demo.

---

Of course, there are multiple ways to do it.

You could alternatively use the [POSIX Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) `\p{Alnum}`, and then enable [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), using `(?U)`.

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\s\\p{Alnum}]+", "");
```

```
Where What is that an animal No It is a plane
Dónde Qué es eso un animal No Es un avión
Onde O que é isso um animal Não É um avião
```

---

Now, if you didn't want spaces, that could be simplified by using `\P{xx}` instead:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(?U)\\P{Alnum}+", "");
```

```
WhereWhatisthatananimalNoItisaplane
DóndeQuéesesounanimalNoEsunavión
OndeOqueéissoumanimalNãoÉumavião
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So much detail, I appreciate it. One more inquiry though - is it possible to do what you have created, but using the Pattern class instead? I have heard bad thing about using String.replaceAll() when working with large data sets and multiple iterations. Pattern.compile allows you to declare the regex just once rather than for every iteration. If you know how I could do this instead, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: @JimmyLee The javadoc of [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) says everything you need to know: *An invocation of this method of the form `str.replaceAll(regex, repl)` yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`*

Comment: Da̱nx̱a̱laga̱litła̱n becomes Danxalagalitłan, so the regex isn't quite universal. Adding `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` retains the diacritics.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in all the languages of the world, however, your requirements could be met by doing this on a language specific basis:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 <put language specific characters to preserve here>]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

I speak English and Korean, and can tell you that punctuation in Korean is identical to that used in English. As indicated above, you can add characters that should be preserved and not considered punctuation for a particular language. For example, let's say the tilde should not be considered punctuation. Then use the regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ~]
```